# How foreach this multidimensional array

Tags: php, mysql, multidimensional-array

My array like this:

```
$data = array(
array('name' => 'john', 'surname' =>'doe', 'car' => 'ford'),
array('name' => 'john', 'surname' =>'doe', 'position' => 'manager'),
array('name' => 'john', 'surname' =>'doe', 'location' => 'LA'),
array('name' => 'michael', 'surname' =>'smith', 'car' => 'toyota'),
array('name' => 'michael', 'surname' =>'smith', 'position' => 'salesman'),
array('name' => 'michael', 'surname' =>'smith', 'location' => 'TX')
);
```

How echo this array like this table:

```
name    | surname | car    | position | location

john    | doe     | ford   | manager  | LA

michael | smith   | toyota | salesman | TX
```

maybe my database tables can give an idea

persons

id | name | surname

1 | john | doe

2 | michael | smith

---

properties

id | properties_name

1 | car

2 | position

3 | location

---

properties_data

id | person_id | properties_id | value

1|1|1|ford

2|1|2|manager

3|1|3|LA

4|2|1|toyota

5|2|2|salesman

6|2|3|TX

Comment: why is your array like that? What have you tried so far?

Comment: Why is `john doe` split across 3 arrays? Where does this come from? What have you tried? If you have 2 `john doe`s this format will never work..

Comment: You want to save that array in your DB table? Or you can write proper SQL query to represent your values as you wish!?

Comment: No I want only echo in table

Comment: Better way would be get correct representation from DB and then you can just easily echo it!? No need to manipulate with data after SQL query result

Answer (score 0):

This will work only for your case:

```
$newArray = array();
foreach ($data as $innerArray) {
    foreach($innerArray as $key => $value) {
        if (isset($newArray[$key])) {
            if (array_search($value, $newArray[$key]) !== false) {
                continue;
            }
        }

        $newArray[$key][] = $value;
    }
}

var_dump($newArray);
```

Better would be construct proper SQL query.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This is useful for me. Also I will review SQL query.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `name` and `surname` as index to normalize the data:

```
$data = array_reduce(
    $data,
    function (array $carry, array $item) {
        $index = $item['name'] . ' ' . $item['surname'];

        return array_merge($carry, [
            $index => $item,
        ]);
    },
    []
);
```

and then echo accordingly:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>
            name
        </th>
        <th>
            surname
        </th>
        <th>
            car
        </th>
        <th>
            position
        </th>
        <th>
            location
        </th>
    </tr>
<?php foreach ($data as $item): ?>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <?php echo $item['name']; ?>
        </td>
        <td>
            <?php echo $item['surname']; ?>
        </td>
        <td>
            <?php echo $item['car']; ?>
        </td>
        <td>
            <?php echo $item['position']; ?>
        </td>
        <td>
            <?php echo $item['location']; ?>
        </td>
    </tr>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</table>
```

However, that might be risky because you might have persons with the same name and surname, and then you would end up merging their data into a single row.

Since your `persons` table has an identifier, it would be better to adjust your query to also select `id` from it and then use it as key:

```
$data = array_reduce(
    $data,
    function (array $carry, array $item) {
        $index = $item['id'](

        return array_merge($carry, [
            $index => $item,
        ]);
    },
    []
);
```

For reference, see:

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-reduce.php